# How to keep group of stacked bar charts in a particular order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Attempting to create stacked bars that should be shown in a particular order.

Data comes from an external API in JSON format.

Any Idea how I can force c3 to do that.

Only order related thing mentioned is to sort by value.

I want the 3 stacked bar to be in a particular order irrespective of the value.

Desired :  P1*, P2*, P3*

Actual :   P3*, P1*, P2*

```
              data: {
                  url: 'ES-URL',
                  mimeType: 'json',
                  x: 'x',
                  names: {
                      "P11": " P-11 header",
                      "P12": " P-12 header",
                      "P21": " P-21 header",
                      "P22": " P-22 header",
                      "P23": " P-23 header",
                      "P24": " P-24 header",
                      "P31": " P-31 header",
                      "P32": " P-32 header",
                      "P33": " P-33 header"
                  },
                  type: "bar",
                  order: false,
                  //order: null,
                  groups: [
                      [
                        "P11",
                        "P12"
                      ],
                      [
                        "P21",
                        "P22",
                        "P23",
                        "P24"
                      ],
                      [
                        "P31",
                        "P32",
                        "P33"
                      ]
                  ],
```

[image]

In the attached image, The bluish stacked column should come after the red one.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that the order in which groups x-order are calculated isn't taken from the order of the groups declaration but from the order in which the data series are originally declared.

For the standard way of declaring data in columns you can get around this by changing this order, though it's now hardwired, I don't have your data source to know if it works with your manner of declaring data (url / json).

The alternative is to rewrite the c3 api getShapeIndices function to work on the groups order rather than the data order. This way it's dynamic too but no guarantees given etc etc

```
chart.internal.oldGetShapeIndices = chart.internal.getShapeIndices;
chart.internal.getShapeIndices = function (typeFilter) {
    var $$ = this, config = $$.config;
    var indices = this.oldGetShapeIndices (typeFilter);

    // collect x-indices of groups, these will currently be in data declaration order, i.e. data1 etc = 0, data5 etc = 2
    var groupXIndex = config.data_groups.map (function (group, i) {
        return indices[group[0]];
    }); // [2,0]
    // sort them
    groupXIndex.sort (function (a,b) { return a - b; });    // [0,2]

    // reassign these sorted indices to dataids by group order
    config.data_groups.forEach (function (group, i) {
        group.forEach (function (did) {
            if (indices[did] !== undefined) {
                indices[did] = groupXIndex[i];
            }
        });
    });
    // now data5 etc has index 0, and data1 etc has index 2

    return indices;
};
chart.flush();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9p62zjtf/